# How to placement author name in centered title at Simple Slide(ConTeXt)?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, context

I have problem about placement author name more than one at my simpleslide and my MWE

```
\usemodule[simpleslides]
[style=Rounded,color=red,
font=Helvetica]
\setupTitle
[ title={TSP\\(Travelling Salesman Problem)},
author={Hirwanto, Novariza Eka Putri, Maya Arum Oktavia, Zara Shelli Meirosa, Sisca Aprila, Dian Nosy Antika, Nani Kurniasih, Dewy Aryani Ruspitasari, Donna Widya Yolanda,Nina Oktariana, Irma Padeta, Dian Ayu Ningtias,Delfa Anesia, Ayu Widya Pratiwi,Fitria Wulandari, Indah Pertiwi, Mareza Yolanda Umar,Revi, Yuri},
date={Date of presentation},
]
\starttext
\placeTitle
\SlideTitle {The first slide}
Write whatever you want.
\SlideTitle {The second slide}
Continue writing.
\stoptext
```

I running my code and the result like this

[image: The Result my Code]

How to placement author name in centered title like this :

[image: The Result Like]

I don't know How edit my simple slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design goal of simpleslides is to make it easy to create a new style. For that reason, existing styles are not designed with customization in mind. So, tweaking an existing style is roughly the same effort as creating a new style (which, is not difficult once you understand the basic ConTeXt environments).

To get the design that you want, I'd change the parameters for `beforeauthor` ... `afterauthor`, and `beforedate`...`afterdate`, and tweak the default MP background.

```
\usemodule[simpleslides]
          [
            style=Rounded,
            color=red,
            font=Helvetica,
          ]


\defineframedtext
  [authorframe]
  [
    width=0.85\textwidth,
    frame=off,
    overlay=none,
    before=,
    after=,
  ]

\definenarrower
    [datenarrower]
    [
      before={\blank[2cm]},
      left={9cm},
      default=left,
    ]

\setupTitle
  [
    before={\blank[force,0.2cm]},
    authorstyle={\switchtobodyfont[12pt]},
    authorcolor=black,
    beforeauthor=\startauthorframe,
    afterauthor=\stopauthorframe,
    beforedate={\startdatenarrower},
    afterdate={\stopdatenarrower},
  ]

% Copied from simpleslides-s-Rounded.tex
\startuniqueMPgraphic{simpleslides:MP:title}
StartPage ;

save a,b,c,d;
numeric a,b,c,d;

a = 4cm ;   b = 3cm ;
c = 8cm ;   d = .7cm ;

save p; path p[] ;
p[1] = ulcorner Page -- ulcorner Page shifted (PaperWidth/2,0) -- 
       llcorner Page shifted (PaperWidth/2,0) -- llcorner Page -- cycle ;

fill Page withcolor \MPcolor{simpleslides:backgroundcolor} ;
fill p[1] withcolor \MPcolor{simpleslides:contrastcolor} ;

z1 = ulcorner Page shifted (PaperWidth/2,-b) ;
z2 = z1 shifted (-c,0) ;
z3 = z2 shifted (0,-a) ;
z4 = z3 shifted (c,0) ;
z5 = z2 shifted (-1.5cm,-a/2) ;

p[2] = z1 -- z2 .. z5 .. z3 -- z4 -- cycle ;
fill p[2] withcolor \MPcolor{simpleslides:backgroundcolor} ;

z6  = llcorner Page shifted (PaperWidth/2,0) ;
z7  = 1/2[z6,z4] ;
z8  = z7 shifted (-.75*b,d/2) ;
z9  = z8 shifted (0,-d) ;
z10 = z9 shifted (1.3*c,0) ;
z11 = z10 shifted (0,d) ;
z12 = z10 shifted (d/2,d/2) ;

p[3] = (z8 -- z9 -- z10 .. z12 .. z11 -- cycle) shifted (0, -PaperHeight/4 + d) ; % AM: Shift added
fill p[3] withcolor \MPcolor{simpleslides:textcolor} ;

StopPage ;
\stopuniqueMPgraphic

\setupTitle
  [ 
    title={TSP\\(Travelling Salesman Problem)},
    author={Hirwanto, Novariza Eka Putri, Maya Arum Oktavia, Zara Shelli Meirosa,
            Sisca Aprila, Dian Nosy Antika, Nani Kurniasih, Dewy Aryani Ruspitasari, Donna
            Widya Yolanda,Nina Oktariana, Irma Padeta, Dian Ayu Ningtias,Delfa Anesia, Ayu
            Widya Pratiwi,Fitria Wulandari, Indah Pertiwi, Mareza Yolanda Umar,Revi, Yuri},
   date={Date of presentation},
 ]
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Ok, Aditya, Succesfull, Any Question  again, How to change green background to be red background ?

Comment: `\definecolOr[simpleslide:backgroundcolor][r=0.8,g=0.2,b=0.2]` (or whatever values you want). If you want to change the green to red, redefine `simpleslide:contrastcolor`